# sendmail stripping From: address for apache www-data@localhost sent PHP mail()

Tags: sendmail, php5, apache2

I am setting up a Science Fair in a Box server that uses apache2, PHP5, and sendmail (although we've uninstalled sendmail and installed postfix with no change in problem ) to send participants their login / registration number.

When the PHP mail() is called it has the properly formatted FROM: address but because sendmail authenticates and is receiving it from www-data@localhost it is stripping out the email address and replacing it with <@> which causes the mail to be sent but filtered out by any server it sends to.

Here is the PHP output verbatim as what is sent to PHP mail():

```
2018-01-23,1516725176,philosophicaldaemon@gmail.com,webmaster@seab-sciencefair.com,Registration for Kiwanis Southeast Alberta Regional Science Fair,We have received a request for the retrieval of your registration number from this email address.  Please find your existing registration number below Registration Number: 380285
```

This is the /var/mail/mail.log excerpt:

```
Jan 23 16:28:36 localhost sendmail[813]: w0NGSaU2000813: Authentication-Warning: seab-sciencefair.com: www-data set sender to @ using -f
Jan 23 16:28:36 localhost sendmail[813]: w0NGSaU2000813: from=@, size=259, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201801231628.w0NGSaU2000813@seab-sciencefair.com>, relay=www-data@localhost
Jan 23 16:28:36 localhost sm-mta[814]: w0NGSasq000814: from=<>, size=575, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201801231628.w0NGSaU2000813@seab-sciencefair.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=ip6-localhost [127.0.0.1]
Jan 23 16:28:36 localhost sendmail[813]: w0NGSaU2000813: to=philosophicaldaemon@gmail.com, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30259, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (w0NGSasq000814 Message accepted for delivery)
Jan 23 16:28:36 localhost sm-mta[816]: STARTTLS=client, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, bits=128/128
Jan 23 16:28:37 localhost sm-mta[816]: w0NGSasq000814: to=<philosophicaldaemon@gmail.com>, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=120575, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [74.125.202.26], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (OK 1516724916 i8si684450iof.207 - gsmtp)
```

We have sent mail from the command line in the past so sendmail can send.

It is sending mail but the FROM: needs to be changed.
So I interpret this as either a configuration problem or an apache2 alias problem.

I note this server is located on digitalocean, is this a cloud configuration issue?

What should I try next? Which software is the likely culprit?

Comment: I'd strongly urge you to use a class like SwiftMailer instead of raw `mail` calls for this sort of reason.

Comment: It's not my code, just trying to get it working, but down the road that might be a better option. I need to get it working with the original sfiab code to validate the setup. Also, allow kids to register for science fair. That sounds like a down the road improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at third example of https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php :

```
<?php mail('nobody@example.com', 'the subject', 'the message', null, '-fwebmaster@example.com');?>
```

The `-f` option is what you need to set the From value. A "@" alone is not good, maybe your settings in `php.ini` are not correct?

But also note that sendmail may decide to discard this value and put something else there, depending on its own settings, normally while putting a warning in logs.